# Spring MVC Method variables

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

As I understand in Spring world objects should be created using dependency injection. should it apply only at class level. I am not sure about Object Orientation here. But what about a method variable.

For example, I have a service level class called `createOrder()` which uses `AddressValidator` class within it (only within that method) to validate the delivery address. One option is to make a class level attribute and `@Autowire` it. But I feel it is not a attribute of the `OrderService` class. Other option is to define it within the `createOrder()` method and instantiate it within the method, which might be against the dependency injection.

What is the right thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can pass the object as reference if the method is called from outside else initializing it inside your method.

if Addressvalidator only validates address you may see if you can use @validate .